# Configuring Wacom one to overlap on a third screen and map it appropriately

Tags: display, wacom

I am a teacher and I have some students in the room and others via web,   using  3 screens my laptop + a Wacom one tablet + a video projector screen.

I need to  (using an HP zbook 15u G3 wich can use 3 screens)

1. sync the video projector screen  with  [ a part of ] my 'Wacom one' screen.
2. Map the stylus only to the Wacom one's screen ( so I can see what I am writing by just looking at my tablet)

So far I was able to do

- (1) but not (2) with plasma
- and (2) but not (1) with gnome.

With plasma even with only 2 screens I was not able to get a correct mapping using kde-config-tablet app (the result was always that  moving the stylus across  tablet will mean moving the pointer from the left of one screen to the right of the other).
I suspected it is bugged but maybe I am just stupid enough not to make it work...

With Gnome the mapping was correct (limited to the tablet) but I could not have anything else than an extended desktop, where the video projector's screen and the wacom's  screen are next to each other and not sync (nor overlapping) .
Pretty Please If someone know any solutions. I am very willing to try (even with command line tool [xrandr?]) I desperately need this to work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good way is simply to use xsetwacom.   (an example in french  :http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/wacom )

-Use

```
xrandr
```

to obtain the list of the screens

-Use

```
xsetwacom list dev
```

to identify the devices [pen,eraser...]

And

```
xsetwacom --set "Name of Wacom device [pen,eraser...]" MapToOutput "Name of the tablet screen"
```

For each device

Cheers